# Symfony 4 : execute the latest migration file

Tags: symfony, migration, symfony4

I have two migrations file and I want to execute the latest one, after show versions I got :

> > Latest Version:2019-10-01 13:23:06 (20191001132306)
> >     and I execute :

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate 20191001132306
```

symfony still execute the first one which have some errors, should I delete it or there a way to execute a specific migration file !!

Comment: -> `doctrine:migrations:execute 20191001132306`

Comment: that's it ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the migration file and delete the record on your database from the table 
migration_versions.

But I'd like to suggest to delete all migration.php files, delete * from migration_versions where 1 = 1 on the database and do again "diff", "migrate" from console.